# Change fan speed when connecting by SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh, display, fan

I have a computer which I interact with by monitor, keyboard and mouse. When I use it, I type the following to set the fan speed to 99%:

```
sudo amdconfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 99"
```

Now I want to interact with it through SSH instead, with no monitor, keyboard or mouse.

I successfully connected via my laptop, and I can browse the computer's files. However when I try to run the fan speed command, I am getting this error:

```
ati_pplib_cmd: Unable to open display `'.
amdconfig: parsing the command-line failed.
```

I didn’t alter my system in any other way than unplugging the monitor. This change must come from either that disconnection or be result of me connecting by SSH. What is it and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running these two lines before the amdconfig line makes it work.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xhost +
```

Thanks to the author of [this](http://w0ss4g3.blogspot.nl/2013/03/using-aticonfig-over-ssh.html).

Answer (score -1):

> Unable to open display

This means it can find your display (because you disconnected your screen) so amdconfig can't start.

I think you should try to control your fan using an other program.